# Pass query variable to a MSDB.dbo.sp_Send_DBMail

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax-error

I have written a SQL query. But its giving me an error.

```
DECLARE @Delimiter Char(1)
SET @Delimiter = CHAR(9)
EXEC MSDB.dbo.sp_Send_DBMail
@profile_name = 'K2MailSetup',
@Recipients='test@xyz.com',
@Subject='Extraction Report',
@Body='Hi',
@Query='set nocount on;
Select Coalesce(replace(replace(A.[type], char(10), ''''), char(13), ''''),'''') as Type,
 try_convert(xml, col).value(''(/collection/object/fields/field/value)[1]'', ''varchar(3)'') 
from (select col= Coalesce(replace(replace(A.[business_line], char(10), ''''), char(13), ''''),'''')
    FROM [EU_OTH_REG].[dbo].[TBL_EU_OTH_TXN_REG_RSDS] A'
```

Error states

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 
>   Incorrect syntax near '/'.

Comment: I am bad in these single quotes. Can you help me with complete query @DaleBurrell

Comment: I did so as told by you.. But it still gives me an error in my original query

Comment: Msg 22050, Level 16, State 1, Line 0
Error formatting query, probably invalid parameters
Msg 14661, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_send_dbmail, Line 517
Query execution failed: Msg 1033, Level 15, State 1, Server MYKULK2DB01Q\MSSQLSTG, Line 13
The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.

Comment: @DaleBurrell See my originial query in the https://stackoverflow.com/q/58298194/12118671

Comment: @NikhilKotian, try my answer below

Comment: @metal I have many fields in my select query whereas these are only for 2.. So was a bit confused.

Comment: Where exactly?Can you edit in my query please? @DaleBurrell

Comment: @NikhilKotian, you only need [Type] and [business_line]?

Comment: @metal Nopes there are many columns.But since i cannot copy all here so i pasted only 2 columns for your reference!

Comment: My query has more than 100 columns. So if I try your approach I would need to manually change all 100 fields. @ϻᴇᴛᴀʟ

Comment: @DaleBurrell I tried putting bracket before A but it isnt working in my original query. It states syntax error

Comment: @Nikhil when I add the bracket it works for me. You need to produce a [mre] for us to be able to assist further, use a temporary table and populate it with some sample data the reproduces the issue.

Comment: Msg 22050, Level 16, State 1, Line 0
Error formatting query, probably invalid parameters
Msg 14661, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_send_dbmail, Line 517
Query execution failed: Msg 1934, Level 16, State 1, Server MYKULK2DB01Q\MSSQLSTG, Line 4
SELECT failed because the following SET options have incorrect settings: 'QUOTED_IDENTIFIER'. Verify that SET options are correct for use with indexed views and/or indexes on computed columns and/or filtered indexes and/or query notifications and/or XML data type methods and/or spatial index operations.

Comment: @Query='set nocount on;


Select try_convert(xml, Coalesce(replace(replace(A.[business_line], char(10), '''''''')
                        , char(13), ''''''''),''''''''))
                        .value(''(/collection/object/fields/field/value)[1]'', ''varchar(3)'') 
                , Coalesce(replace(replace(A.[type], char(10), ''''''''), char(13), ''''''''),'''''''') as [Type]
    FROM [EU_OTH_REG].[dbo].[TBL_EU_OTH_TXN_REG_RSDS] A',
 @Attach_Query_Result_As_File = 1,

Comment: I used this above query and it gave me error.

Comment: well, xml methods will not work of quoted_identifier is off.,, you need to turn it on. see below updates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found 2 issues here.

> 1. your subquery is not properly closed
> 2. your quotes are not property terminated

```
Declare @Query as nvarchar(1000) 
Set @Query='set nocount on; 
            set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER on;
            Select try_convert(xml, Coalesce(replace(replace(A.[business_line], char(10), '''''''')
                        , char(13), ''''''''),''''''''))
                        .value(''(/collection/object/fields/field/value)[1]'', ''varchar(3)'') 
                , Coalesce(replace(replace(A.[type], char(10), ''''''''), char(13), ''''''''),'''''''') as [Type]
                from [EU_OTH_REG].[dbo].[TBL_EU_OTH_TXN_REG_RSDS] A;'
```

Answer (score 1):

The trick to dynamic SQL is to make sure the SQL works before trying to make it dynamic.

Your query needs multiple tweaks before it works as a basic SQL query:

```
set nocount on;

select coalesce(replace(replace(A.[type], char(10), ''''), char(13), ''''),'''') as Type
  , try_convert(xml, col).value('(/collection/object/fields/field/value)[1]', 'varchar(3)') 
from (
    select col = coalesce(replace(replace([business_line], char(10), ''''), char(13), ''''),''''), Type
    FROM [EU_OTH_REG].[dbo].[TBL_EU_OTH_TXN_REG_RSDS]
) A;
```

Then and only then, convert to dynamic SQL by doubling all single quotes:

```
declare @Query as nvarchar(1000) = 'set nocount on;

select coalesce(replace(replace(A.[type], char(10), ''''), char(13), ''''),'''') as Type
  , try_convert(xml, col).value(''(/collection/object/fields/field/value)[1]'', ''varchar(3)'') 
from (
    select col = coalesce(replace(replace([business_line], char(10), ''''), char(13), ''''),''''), Type
    FROM [EU_OTH_REG].[dbo].[TBL_EU_OTH_TXN_REG_RSDS]
) A;'

exec(@Query);
```